# Original titles on IMDb?

Tags: imdb

Is there a way to get IMDb to show a movie's original title in the languages original script? So that a Japanese title is showed in Kanji/Hiragana or a Russian title is showed in Cyrillic?

Answer (score 1):

At https://secure.imdb.com/register-imdb/siteprefs you can, if you are logged in, set the *Title Display Country* to *Original*.  However, this does not put it in the original script, but it does put the title in the original language.